# How to setup/access page in subdirectory of separate project for a Laravel/OctoberCMS website?

Tags: php, html, laravel, octobercms, matomo

I have a website running an OctoberCMS theme that I built. It's running on a server from DigitalOcean. I need to add a separate project (namely code from Matomo analytics) on the same server and access a public page (e.g. my_site.com/matomo). I'm new enough to Laravel and server configurations that I'm unsure of how I need to configure the index.php files or maybe something like .htaccess so that I can access my_site.com/matomo.

Here's my file structure

```
/var/www/html/
     index.php (serves the pages of my project)
     artisan
     bootstrap/
     config/
     modules/
     plugins/
     server.php
     storage/
     themes/
     vendor/
     matomo/ (for installing the analytics for the site)
         index.php 
         matomo.php
         piwik.php
         config/
         a number of other files I can enumerate if necessary
```

I've followed [the instructions](https://matomo.org/docs/installation/#start-the-installation) from matomo but to no avail. When I try to go to my_site.com/matomo I just get a 404 from my website with my theme's formatting for it.

I know this shouldn't be hard. Thanks!

EDIT: The home page of my website is at my_site.com, as desired. The various pages are at my_site.com/page_name. This is configured fine for my purposes.

Now, for Matomo, the instructions say:

> Open your FTP client and upload the Matomo files in ‘binary mode’ to the desired location on your web server. For example using the Filezilla FTP client, you can enable Binary mode transfer in the top menu Transfer > Transfer type > Binary). All files can be uploaded to a “analytics” sub-directory in your public www folder, for example http://yourdomain.org/analytics/ or you could setup Matomo in its own subdomain and upload all the files at http://analytics.example.org/
> If you have SSH access to your server, you can use it instead of FTP as it is much faster: run
> wget https://builds.matomo.org/matomo.zip && unzip matomo.zip

So, I used the wget option to add it to what I believe is the "public www folder", `/var/www/html`. So the instructions lead me to believe I can go to my_site.com/analytics/ and then view the GUI webpage for further install and setup. However, this doesn't work as it takes to a 404 page that's setup for the rest of my site. I also don't know that I'd expect it to work as none of the files or folders in Matomo are named "analytics" -- I've also tried my_site.com/matomo for the record. So, this is to say, I don't know where the Matomo page is presented.

Comment: Please share more details such as. What is the current laravel domain path ( not real domain just example). What is the current Matomo domain path. And lastly what is the domains path that you want for both laravel and Matomo.

Comment: @MohdAlomar I've added more detail. let me know if I didn't provide information on something and I'll put it up there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any experience with `Matomo`, but from the question I understood that you want to install two software X as `CMS` and Y as `Matomo`.

Your web server(I assume Apache is the web server) will serve all request to the following path: `/var/www/html/index.php`. Which belong to software X. Your request `my_site.com/matomo` will be served to software X, and because X doesn't expect this request it will output `404 Not Found` error.

**The first solution:** which is the bad solution and harder solution is to edit `/var/www/html/index.php` and combine it with Y `index.php` if request have matomo in the URL.

**The second solution:** which is the optimal and better solution is to separate X and Y. It could be done in several ways:

- You can combine all X files in a folder under `/var/www/html/x`, and all Y files in folder under `/var/www/html/y`. Then you can access x using the following URL `my_site.com/x` and y using `my_site.com/y`.
- If the first way in not possbile because you need to have X as root URL like `my_site.com`. Then you can combine all Y file under the following folder `/var/www/html/matomo`. Then you need to create sub domain (virtual host for Y).

**Create virtual host using Ubuntu and Apache:**

`sudo touch /etc/apache2/sites-available/matomo.my_site.com.conf`

Then edit the file using your favorite text editor I will use `nano`

`sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/matomo.my_site.com.conf`

and past the following code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@my_site.com
    ServerName matomo.my_site.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/matomo/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Change `my_site.com` to your domain.

Then you need to enable the virtual host

`sudo a2ensite /etc/apache2/sites-available/matomo.my_site.com.conf`

Then restart apache to see the result.

`sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Your `matomo` will be under the following URL matomo.my_site.com

If you are not using Ubuntu or Apache, tell me what are you using to update my answer.

Comment: Thanks @MohdAlomar, I'm pursuing creating the subdomain and have made it to trying to restart apache. However, when I go to restart it, I get `AH00526: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/webdock.conf`. Right now, `webdock.conf` is empty. I assume I need to add something here in order to get it to work? Cheers

Comment: Please run the following commands to debug. 
1- sudo systemctl status apache2.service -l --no-pager 
2- sudo journalctl -u apache2.service --since today --no-pager 
3- sudo apachectl configtest

Comment: Also are you sure the webdock,conf is empty run the following command to double check. 
1- sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/webdock.conf 
2- sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/webdock.conf

Comment: Not sure what happened yesterday but after repeating the steps and skipping the a2ensite command, this worked. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your most welcome. Not sure what could be the issue but a2ensite is once per host so no need to repeat it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to fix anything in index.php. Analytics counters can be added to the layout (~/themes/mytheme/layout/mylayout.htm) of the page between the

```
<head>
...
</head>
```

or

```
<body>
...
</body>
```

according to the instructions of your meter

Comment: I'm stuck on the actual install of the analytics. I added more detail to the question. I still need to set up the analytics on my server

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues/1615. You need to add the folder you want to allow access to as an exclusion to the October CMS .htaccess, and then also disable the line that disables running any PHP file other than index.php.

So replace `RewriteEngine On` with

```
RewriteEngine On

# Allow access to Matomo
RewriteRule ^(matomo)($|/) - [L]
```

and then comment out `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$` so it becomes `# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$`.